# Form validation !='' in if statement?

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me whats wrong with this code, im validating a form making sure all the fields have text in them before anyone can submit. everything works until i put in the `!='' var.` I am sure the id's are correct

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script> 
<script language="javascript">


$(document).ready(function() {

// declare the flags outside the other functions

 var username_ready = false;
 var email_ready = false;




function checkSubmitStatus() {
var emailvalue = $("#email").val();
 var usernamevalue = $('#username').val();
 var firstvalue = $('#first').val();
 var lastvalue = $('#last').val();
 var passwordvalue = $('#password').val();
if (username_ready && email_ready && emailvalue!='' && usernamevalue!='' &&  firstvalue!='' && lastvalue!='' && passwordvalue!=''){ 

  $("#register").prop('disabled',false); 
}
else {$("#register").prop('disabled',true);}
}
```

and here is my form code so you can see if thats the issue...

```
<p>First Name: <input id="first" type="text" name="name" maxlength="100"> </p>
<p>Last Name: <input id="last" type="text" name="name" maxlength="100"> </p>
<p> Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email" maxlength="100" />
<span id="box" style="display:none"></span></p>
User Name : <input name="username" type="text" id="username" value="" maxlength="15" />
<span id="msgbox" style="display:none"></span>
<p> Password: <input id="password" type="password" name="password"> </p>
```

Comment: I missed the part where you set username_ready and email_ready to true.

Comment: thats part is what i know works on its own, its ajax that checks to see if the username or email already exists and if they dont it sets true if they do it sets false. False deactivates submit button, true activates. so that if statement should activate it.

Comment: BTW, you don't need the `!= ''` part. `if (username_ready && email_ready && emailvalue && usernamevalue) { ... }` should work as well. Empty strings get converted to `false`, non-empty -- to `true`.

Comment: thanks for the tip, thats what i had originally however after it not working i tweaked everything to make sure . Thanks!!!!!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You spelt your variable name `firstvalue` incorrectly:

```
firstvale!=''
```

**Edit**

Move these 5 lines:

```
 var emailvalue = $("#email").val();
 var usernamevalue = $('#username').val();
 var firstvalue = $('#first').val();
 var lastvalue = $('#last').val();
 var passwordvalue = $('#password').val();
```

From where they are to right under `function checkSubmitStatus(){` and above your big if statement.

Where they are now, they are only assigned once, to the value of the form when the page first loads which I'm assuming at least one of them is empty.

You need to move those lines into your `checkSubmitStatus()` function so that they get updated whenever the function is called. The final result should look like:

```
var username_ready = false;
var email_ready = false;

function checkSubmitStatus() {

    var emailvalue = $("#email").val();
    var usernamevalue = $('#username').val();
    var firstvalue = $('#first').val();
    var lastvalue = $('#last').val();
    var passwordvalue = $('#password').val();


    if (username_ready && email_ready && 
        emailvalue!='' && usernamevalue!='' &&
        firstvalue!='' && lastvalue!='' && passwordvalue!=''){ 

        $("#register").prop('disabled',false); 
    } else {
        $("#register").prop('disabled',true);
    }
}
```

Comment: haha, i did but thats not the issue i tried troubleshooting by removing the different parts one by one and it only works when username_ready && email_ready are the only parts to the if statement. So there is something wrong with the var or the !='' part of my code?

Comment: @user860869 where do you call your function `checkSubmitStatus()` from? By that time perhaps the values of `$('#email').val()` etc. have changed. Try moving your `var emailvalue = $("#email").val();` and the four similar lines under it into the start of the function.

Comment: they are in the start ... first thing and no other var defined by that name ever, not even close.

Comment: @user860869 Did you move them there? Because in the code above they are not in the start. They aren't in the function at all.

Comment: thats exactly what its like sorry for not including full code from beginning.

Comment: @user860869 I want you to move those 5 lines from where they are to right under `function checkSubmitStatus(){` and above your big if statement. Where they are now, they are only assigned once, to the value of the form when the page first loads which I'm assuming at least one of them is empty. You need to move those lines into your `checkSubmitStatus()` function so that they get updated whenever the function is called.

Comment: great, maybe this will help someone else that is essentially learning off these forums like me!

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your code, I get the feeling that it's copy-pasted together from different parts of your code. What might be happening is that `emailvalue`, `usernamevalue` etc are really out of scope at the time the `checkSubmitStatus` is called. I might also be wrong, but it's hard to tell more based on the provided code, since it seems to be alright.

You could do `alert(emailvalue);` before the if statement to see if you get `undefined` or some value. If it's undefined, you probably have a scope issue.

From the above code it also seems that you assign those variables values, before anything is really entered or the form is submitted.

Comment: omg thats right you guy are great i cant believe i didnt see that.

Comment: thanks i got it to work, var defined before the function! my bad.